# How to restart all the Apache Ambari client on all the installed hosts in one go?

Tags: apache, service, client-server, ambari

We have one cluster setup of Apache Ambari with single server and 8 client hosts. I was wondering how can I restart Ambari client services on all the hosts in one go or in one click or may be by running a script. One way I was aware of is to write a script which will remotly connect to each of the hosts and restart the apche Ambari client service. And other traditional way is login to each system and manually restart the services. I want to know is there any way from amabari server using which I can restart it on all client hosts or any other?

Comment: Sounds like a question for http://serverfault.com rather than SO.... See [help/on-topic]

Comment: Yeah right, moved to serverfault.